# this is not working within prototype functions when called in express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, this, prototype

I am facing a strange error in node.js express framework.

I created a file say **test.js** which has the following code

```
function a(){

}

a.prototype.b = function(){
    this.c("asdsad");
}

a.prototype.c = function(string){
    console.log("ccc"+string)
}

/*var ob = new a();
ob.b();*/

module.exports = a;
```

and another file **call_test.js**

```
var test = require('./test');
var test_ob = new test();
test_ob.b();
```

when I am running node call_test.js it is giving me correct output cccasdsad

BUT, when I am calling test.js using express middleware in file **express_test.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var test = require('./test');
var test_ob = new test();

app.get('/testAPI',test_ob.b);
```

I am getting error this.c is not a function when I am hitting testAPI.

Can you tell me why ***this*** is not working when using in middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

The calling context of your `app.get` line is `app`, so when the `b` function tries to run `this.c("asdsad");`, it's trying to access `app.c` when you're actually trying to access `test_ob.c`.

When passing the `b` function to `app.get`, *bind* the `b` function's `this` value to the `test_ob` so it will be referenced properly:

```
app.get('/testAPI',test_ob.b.bind(test_ob));
```

Comment: perfect, thank you so much for this. but now its looking messy :D instead of just test.b